# Does anything like NSPredicateEditor exist for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, nspredicateeditor

As far as I know NSPredicateEditor isn't available for iOS. But has anyone created something similar for iOS?

I imagine it would be fairly difficult UI wise since the screen is much smaller but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible in theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [PredicateEditor](https://github.com/arvindhsukumar/PredicateEditor) which resembles what's done in the [Workflow app](https://workflow.is).